# Run bash script from file in C

Tags: c, bash

I have this part of code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main(void)
   {
       FILE * fp;
       char * line = NULL;
       size_t len = 0;
       ssize_t read;

       fp = fopen("./file_commands", "r");
       if (fp == NULL)
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

       while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        //   printf("%s", line);
       system(line);
       }

       fclose(fp);
       if (line)
           free(line);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

In file_commands i want to put and be able to run a bash script like the following: `\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80` 
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: hm. _i want to put and be able to run a bash script like the following: \x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68_ the hexdump isn't *bash* script.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to go line by line like that. There are actually several things you're doing wrong that are causing this code to fail, but the most important is that **going line by line through the bash file does not conserve resources**.

In fact it wastes resources. Every time you make a call to `system` your OS creates a new process for the execution of the command. You would actually save system resources if you just did this

```
int result = system("./file_commands");
```

instead of trying to execute every line of that file in a separate call to `system`.

Comment: That is not the point.. What i want is to run the above hexdump (as jm666 mentioned) from file as it would have been run if it was inside stack

Comment: @J.S ok I think I understand. That is tricky...maybe impossible. It also seems silly. Did you compile a bunch of programs and paste the output to lines all in the same file?

Comment: I am just trying to make the same hexdump which i would put into the stack to execute normally, to make it run from console like if i am using it `system (line)`

Comment: @J.S that is simply not how `system` works. In fact, that is really not how C works. For one thing, `system` **always** creates a new process, which is sandboxed from your old process, i.e. it will never run in the current stack. There really isn't a way to do what you're trying to do. I suggest you find another route of attack.